# golang, combine 2 method have same content

Tags: go

I have 2 method of 2 struct A and B.
The content of 2 Method is the same.

```
func (t *A) TestGo() error {
  ...
  return t.abc(); // call method of struct
}
```

Could I write a func able to input 2 type. Like this

```
fun TestGo(t .?.) error {
  ...
  return t.abc();
}
```

It will easier to maintain in later. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an interface for structs with this method:

```
type ABCer interface {
    abc() error
}
```

Then your `TestGo` function can accept this interface:

```
func TestGo(t ABCer) error {
    return t.abc()
}
```

[Live demo](https://play.golang.org/p/WqeSEdOIUI).

Comment: You rock! Thanks a ton!